# Object reference error setting a string variable

Tags: vb.net

When I try to run the following code, I get this error:

> Object reference not set to instance of object

```
conString = "Data Source=HQ10-1CT-PC0; Initial Catalog=CONTACT_DB; Integrated Security=True"
con.ConnectionString = conString

'Problem is on these two lines
Dim messageID As String
messageID = Me.Tag.ToString

sql = "select * from Message_tb where M_ID =@Mess_ID"
Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand(sql, con)
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(“@Mess_ID", messageID)
con.Open()
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
da.SelectCommand = cmd
da.Fill(ds, “myMessage")
'Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables("myMessages")
con.Close()
ViewMessage()
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

`Me.Tag` doesn't have a value, and therefore calling `.ToString()` for the missing value is not possible.

```vb
Dim messageID As StringD = If(Me.Tag?.ToString(), "")
conString = "Data Source=HQ10-1CT-PC0; Initial Catalog=CONTACT_DB; Integrated Security=True"
sql = "select * from Message_tb where M_ID =@Mess_ID"

Using con As New SqlConnection(conString), _
      cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, con)

    cmd.Parameters.Add(“@Mess_ID", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 10).Value =  messageID
    da.SelectCommand = cmd
    da.Fill(ds, “myMessage")
End Using
ViewMessage()
```